# How to display <text> in a classic report when no data found by merging all the columns

Tags: oracle-apex

Is it possible to display an oracle apex classic report with all it's heading when  no data found. Something in the below format

[image]

Comment: No, as far as I can tell - not in a simple manner, anyway, using Apex' built-in capabilities. What about more *complex* manner? I don't even want to think about it. "No data found" - which is default message (you can change) - is just OK for me and my users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

Let's say you have 4 columns. Prepare HTML of these 4 columns thead + tbody of colspan="4" with a text "No Data" and put these HTML in the attribute of the classic report of "When No Data Found"

Then you will have what you wanted.

[image]

```
<table class="t-Report-report">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="t-Report-colHead" align="left" id="NAME">Name</th>
        <th class="t-Report-colHead" align="left" id="CITY">City</th>
        <th class="t-Report-colHead" align="left" id="TEL1">Tel1</th>
        <th class="t-Report-colHead" align="left" id="EMAIL1">Email1</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody><tr><td class="t-Report-cell" colspan="4">No Data</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```